# How to change height and width according to the screen, (with minimum)

Tags: html, css, width

There is a box in the center of the page which will be presented as slides.  I would like to increase its size according to the users' screens. and also set a minimum size, so when a screen is so small but my box wont be smaller.
Here is my code:

```
    .container{ 
    width:1000px;
    height:500px; 
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    margin:-275px 0 0 -500px;
}
.main-content{
    float:left;
    width:1000px;
    height:500px; 
    position:absolute;
    background:url(../img/map.png) no-repeat center top;
    border: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) solid 1px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="main-content">hi</div> 
</div>
```

I think I have to use min-height/width but should my actual width and height be in percentage? it didnt work in px.
So generally I am looking for a standard solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use percentages instead of fixed values:

```
.main-content{
    float:left;
    width: 80%; /* Use the percentage that fits to your needs */
    height: 80%;
    min-height: 300px; /* You can also define minimum width and height */
    min-width: 300px;
    position:absolute;
    background:url(../img/map.png) no-repeat center top;
    border: rgba(255,255,255,0.2) solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I should make .container in percentages instead as everything will go inside this box. right? and my other question is that, should I make all items inside this div in percentage too? for example if there is picture ?!

Comment: Yes. Everything inside should use percentages, otherwise something could overflow the container.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea for the background? to decrease its side accordingly in a div ?!

Comment: Have a look to the [background-size property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp). Particularly the cover and contain options.